# Replace Column Value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, data-analysis

I have a column 'Height' in Dataset as below.

```
      Height
0       6-2
1       6-6
2       6-5
3       6-5
4      6-10
5       6-9
6       6-8
7       7-0
```

and it's type is  `dtype: object` Now I want to convert it into float i.e 6.2, 6.6 I tried with **replace method** but it didn't work. Can you suggest me how to do it? I am new to Pandas.

Comment: `df.Height = df.Height.str.replace('-','.')`?

Comment: @krewsayder makes a good point. if the units here is feet, then 6ft 2in is not the same as 6.2

Comment: Yes @ChrisA   You are right But Since I am learning pandas I want to know how it works to change dtype and also how to replace with regex. Don't worry this data is for learning purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for replace substrings and convert to floats by :

```
df['Height'] = df['Height'].str.replace('-','.').astype(float)
```

Or use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with `regex=True` for replace substrings:

```
df['Height'] = df['Height'].replace('-','.', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Comment: @yatu - test it, it is substrings, so necessary

Answer (score 1):

You can map the column with a lambda function to change it.

```
df.loc[:,'Height'] = df.loc[:,'Height'].map(lambda x: float(str(x).replace('-','.')))
```

I don't know your use case though, but if that's inches be careful.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Don't worry this data is for learning the purpose.